# LIBSVM easy.py and grid.py doing worse that svm-train

Tags: libsvm

I am facing a problem with libsvm and I am hoping you can help me

When I use svm-train.exe with default parameters like this...

```
svm-train  dikomou
svm-predict  dikomou.t  dikomou.model   dikomou.t.predict
```

I get accuracy  84.72%

When I use scaling  [-1, 1] ,and same scaling for training and testing file like this....

```
svm-scale -l -1 -u 1 -s range1 dikomou > dikomou.scale
svm-scale -r range1 dikomou.t > dikomou.t.scale
svm-train dikomou.scale
svm-predict dikomou.t.scale dikomou.scale.model dikomou.t.predict
```

I get less accuracy  81.94%

If I do the scaling for 0 to 1  I get accuracy  87.5%

So I keep the 0 to 1 scaling.

BUT when I use `grid.py` with the 0 to 1 scaled data like this

```
grid.py dikomou.scale
.. 
8  0.0078125   84 ,25 

$ ./svm-train -c 8 -g 0.0078125 dikomou.scale
$ ./svm-predict dikomou.t.scale dikomou.scale.model dikomou.t.predict
```

I get cross validation rate 84.25% and total accuracy of 79.166%  and best given c = 8 gamma= 0.0078125

So the `grid.py` gives me less!!! accuracy  than the one using the svm train with defaults. So I have two questions.

1. How is this possible??
2. What are the default values of `c` and `gamma` the svm train uses?? (I cant find this clearly in the documentation. is gamma 1/number of features   and  c = 1?) and why the do better than when I use the `grid.py`?

`easy.py` also gives me worse results than the defaults. what can i do?

Comment: I am also learning libsvm,
In the file svm-train.c
    "-g gamma : set gamma in kernel function (default **1/num_features**)\n"
    "-r coef0 : set coef0 in kernel function (default **0**)\n"